# Duplicate zip entry [okhttp-2.4.0.jar:com/squareup/okhttp/Address.class]

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have android multi-project setup with okhttp as part of multiple projects

In project A, okhttp is included in the source code.
In project B, okhttp comes with part of a library dependency.

When I build, I get the below error.

> Execution failed for task ':Events-Android:events:proguardFlavDebug'.
>   java.io.IOException: Can't write [/Users/gatorboy/events/Events-Android/events/build/intermediates/classes-proguard/dfmobile/debug/classes.jar] (Can't read [/Users/gatorboy/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup.okhttp/okhttp/2.4.0/40340c0748190fe897baf7bffbc1b282734294e5/okhttp-2.4.0.jar(;;;;;;!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)] (Duplicate zip entry [okhttp-2.4.0.jar:com/squareup/okhttp/Address.class]))

I couldnt exclude okhttp from Project B as it is a different version compared to the okhttp source code in Project A. Is there any other way to resolve this issue?

There are similar posts on stackoverflow but I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: What is the output of `gradle androidDependencies`?

Answer (score 3):

I got same error. Just add these line to `build.gradle` and it works for me !

```
configurations{
    all*.exclude module: 'okhttp'
    all*.exclude module: 'okio'
}
```

Comment: thanks. ksoap2 and retrofit have this problem. with your solution is every thing's is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two versions of the same library in the same application.  If you ***ABSOLUTELY*** need two versions of the same library then you need to repackage one of the versions using the `jarjar` tool.

Otherwise your never going to get two different versions of the same lib into the same app.

Best fix is to use the same version for both packages... if that's not an option then `jarjar` repackaging is the only solution, but it's not a good solution as the lib must be manually repackaged again if you need a different version later.

JarJar reference: https://code.google.com/p/jarjar/